# Como ter todas as branches do repositório na minha máquina local?

Tags: git, github, branch, git-flow

Gostaria de ter todas as branches que há no repositório para a minha máquina. Não encontrei nenhuma forma para isso, mesmo pesquisando como fazer, sobrou apenas vir aqui perguntar e tentar achar a solução.

Contextualizando Melhor, no meu repositório há 12 branches, e quando faço o comando `git branch` aparece apenas 3 das 12 e essas foram as que eu criei localmente. Queria ter as 12 branches na minha máquina

Comment: Tentou `git branch -a`?

Answer (score 1):

1. **Buscar branchs**

Para pegar todas as branch’s é fácil:

`git branch -a`

Onde o -a lista tanto branch’s locais como remotas.

Usando esse comando e Powershell você pode interar na coleção de strings:

`git branch -a | % {$_ }`

Rodando o comando acima você terá o mesmo resultado no terminal do primeiro, pois ele irá basicamente fazer o *output* das string. Com isso, é trabalhar com elas para chegar aos nomes das branch’s e poder executar um checkout.

Porém, existe o comando abaixo:

`git ls-remote`

Ele lista as referências do repositório remoto, e para filtrar as branch locais é só usar os parâmetros:

`git ls-remote --heads origin`

2. **-match e $matches**

Agora que podemos ter uma coleção de referências, vamos buscar filtrar somente o nome das branch’s.

Para isso faremos uso do operador de comparação do Powershell -match. Passando o pattern, baseado em RegEx, ‘refs/heads/(.*)’, iremos testar, se a referência na coleção é qualquer coisa que tenha no início da string refs-barra-heads-barra.

`git ls-remote --heads origin | % { $_ -match 'refs/heads/(.*)' }`

Executando a linha acima, teremos a confirmação de que todas batem com o padrão. Mas… o objetivo não é esse ao usar o -match. O legal é que o Powershell irá criar uma coleção dos matches, com nome de variável $matches, sempre! Essa variável é um hashtable key-value, ou chave-valor, é possível chamá-la na sessão digitando o seu nome:

`$matches`

Portanto se quisermos só o nome da branch, basta pegar o conteúdo no índice 1!

O que é preciso fazer agora é passar essa coleção para a próxima execução de comando, mas ignorando a resposta da iteração, ou seja os True. Para isso usamos out-null, porém, repassamos os matches para serem processados no próximo pipe, o comando fica assim:

`git ls-remote --heads origin | % { $_ -match 'refs/heads/(.*)' | out-null; $matches[1] }`

3. **git checkout**

Agora só é preciso iterar na coleção de nomes, fazendo o checkout das branch’s.

`git ls-remote --heads origin | % { $_ -match 'refs/heads/(.*)' | out-null; $matches[1] } | % { git checkout $_ }`

Só mandar o push para o outro remote!